# c# asp.net Why doesn't the request page see then posted values?

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is the codebehind the second page.

```
namespace ns1
{
    public partial class second : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int loop1;
            NameValueCollection coll;
            coll = Request.Form;
            String[] arr1 = coll.AllKeys;
            for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++)
            {
                lblDebug.Text = lblDebug.Text + "Form: " + arr1[loop1] + "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the 1st page with the form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="second.aspx">
<div>
    type: <asp:TextBox ID="testType" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    data: <asp:TextBox ID="testData" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblDebug" runat="server" Text="text" />
</div>
</form>
```

I can point the form to http://httpbin.org/post and you will see what you expect to see.

But in the codebehind of the second page is it that arr1 doesn't have anything.  arr1.lenght is = 0.

Why?

Comment: Asp.Net is funny that way. It goes against standard HTTP convention. To access form fields of another page in the same application [use the `PreviousPage` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0)

Comment: Pretty sure they need a `name` attribute (and doesn't look like you need the ID attribute).  Change `ID` to `name` and see how you go.  ID allows you to access the field in *that page's` code behind file.  But for `POST` data it is referenced by name.

Comment: I'll try PreviousPage

Comment: You know what is interesting?  This is the reply from  http://httpbin.org/post    :    "form": {
    "Button1": "Button", 
    "testData": "asdasdasd", 
    "testType": "asdasd"
  },  extemporanious info redacted.  httpbin doesn't need the name attribute to exist.  AND the code you see above?  Snipped right off of Microsoft's web site specific to this purpose.

Comment: Asp.Net adds the `name` attribute to server side controls. View the page source.

Comment: Good to know @Crowcoder, rarely view the horrible source ASP generates.

Comment: PreviousPage doesn't exists no matter what I've tried.  "instance not set to an object"

Comment: @user2367083 did you try it with the `PreviousPageType` directive? I have used it that way in the past so I know it works, but I don't recall every step.

Comment: I did not.  The directive requires VirtualPath.  In my end solution I do not have control over what page is going to be posting to mine.  The poster is from a third party

Comment: Request.Form is constantly empty.  But I can use javascript on the page to access form values being sent.  It is exactly this that is failing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx#Anchor_1